# How to add a Rating Bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How to add a Rating Bar programmatically android? 
and how to set the count of stars. sometimes even if i set the number of stars it wont appear in the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is wrap content over

```
// first create a layout 
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
// now you will have to set width and height 
ll.setMinimumWidth(300);
ll.setMinimumHeight(100);
// now init Rating bar
RatingBar rb = new RatingBar(getApplicationContext());
// now set num of stars
rb.setNumStars(5);
// adding ratingBar into the created layout
ll.addView(rb);
// get the current layout
LinearLayout l = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
// now add the layout
l.addView(ll);
```

Here is the layout resouce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try some liblary to make ratingbar.. like https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialRatingBar

Answer (score 1):

For adding rating bar programmatically you need to add this code

```
//parent layout in which you want to add rating bar
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.d_layout);
RatingBar r = new RatingBar(MainActivity.this);
linearLayout.addView(r);
//how many starts you want to show,parent layout width must be wrap_content
r.setNumStars(6);
r.setRating(Float.parseFloat("1.5"));
```